# hasMany relationship and where clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a `hasMany` relationship on `ModelA` thats is linked to `ModelB`. In my query, I have a `where` clause where I look for specific information in `ModelB` relationship.

Everything is fine if the relationship is found between `ModelA` and `ModelB` but if there is no relationship between `ModelA` and `ModelB` I get an error that specific column (from `ModelB`) was not found.

I already tried various methods to check if the relationship is present without no success (including: `has()`, `relation()->exists()`).

I could append attribute and filter out results after executing the query but with this approach my pagination numbers get messed up.

Anything I can do to check if the relationship exists before running the query?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to check if model relation exist or not:

```
if (count($model->relation))
{
  // exists
}
```

Comment: What you're suggesting would only work after getting the results (e.g. after executing `->get()`).

I load the relationship like so `$results = ModelA::with('ModelB')` and then do something like `$results->whereJsonLength('ModelB.jsonColumn', 0)`

and only then do `$shipments->paginate()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$result = ModelA::whereIn('relation_id', ModelB::where('column', $data)->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I needed to use a relationship instead of a `leftJoin` was that I needed to get all results as in `hasMany` relationship as an array for specific row rather than getting the first item as with `leftJoin` and getting several same rows with different column from the `leftJoin`.

However, I've tried everything and nothing worked so I gave `leftJoin` another shot and made a more complicated query by hand but in the end got the result that I needed.

To solve the "getting all results" from the `leftJoin` rather than one (I only needed one column from `ModelB` but there might be several relationships) I used `\DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(ModelB.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS catName")` in my `select()` and then used `groupBy->('ModelA.id')` before getting results. This way, the all the relationship results were grouped to a one column from `ModelB` with a `', '` separator.

Crazy solution to a crazy problem but it worked.